# How to read a .txt etc from a manifest.json?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome-Extension that closes a tab if its URL contains a specific word. My plan was to create a .txt file (if this doesn't work other files would be okay as well) containing a list of those words. I would then try to read this file from my manifest.json using:

`"matches": [
       //read the words from the file
      ],`

So I'm searching a way to read a file via json.

Comment: `manifest.json` is a static file. You cannot modify it programmatically. But you can programmatically accomplish your objective using a background script.

Comment: manifest.json is an inert file, it doesn't run, so it can't read anything. You can generate manifest.json on your local computer by writing a separate script (a python script or a node.js script, and so on) that converts words from a file into proper URL patterns and writes them into `"matches"` inside manifest.json.

Comment: Okay, thanks that sounds a little complicated. So wouldn‘t it be easier to add a if Statement in the background.js, That reads the file?